# Как удалить последний коммит в gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

сделал коммит не в ту ветку и залил это на gitlab теперь не знаю как удалить в гитлабе, непосредственно на локальном хранилище удалил с помощью вот такой команды `git reset --soft HEAD~`

Comment: [git revert <commit>](https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/problems/revert-git-commit)

Comment: Коммиты в удаленных репозиториях нельзя удалять. Делайте новый коммит, откатывающий результаты предыдущего.

Comment: @user7860670, кто вам такое сказал? Вы наверное путаете термины *удалённый* репозиторий и *опубликованный* (*опубликованными* могут считаться не только все ветки некоторого репозитория, но и любое подмножество веток, начиная с одной) . Это совершенно ортогональные вещи.

Comment: @0andriy Нет, я ничего не путаю.

Comment: @user7860670, удачи вам в познании мира!

Comment: Если у вас ветка не является «опубликованной», т.е. вы не придерживаетесь в ней правила, что вся история должна идти без нарушений, то `git push -f ...` вам поможет. У GitLab, если я правильно помню, есть «предохранитель» против таких действий, поэтому его надо выключить.